# problem in installing : unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation, 16.10

When I try to install any application or update, it shows unmet dependencies- Try apt-get -f install.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the following command

```
   sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update
```